# Javascript - click() does not work on text area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a script for comment automation. In step one, code is supposed to stimulate a click on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cai2W.png) text area (inside the red box), but nothing happens.
 I've used `document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].click();` but that doesn't seem to work. Apparently the click() method is working only on some div tag elements in the webpage I'm working on, but that's another problem. 
I tried placing the comment using `.value`, and although that technically adds text to the text area, the "post" button is still disabled. For it to be enabled, I need to click on the text area first and after at least one valid keypress event, the post button is enabled. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2GB2.png). Here's the code I can see for the text box and post button.

```html
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_ablz _aaoc" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px !important;"></textarea>
<button class="_acan _acao _acas" type="submit" disabled=""><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacw _adda _aad0 _aad6 _aade">Post</div></button>
```

**EDIT** 
I've been suggested to use `.focus()`, and although it does work in code snippets placed here, it doesn't work on the target website. When I tried executing `document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].focus();`,  'undefined' was returned to console. But the text area wasn't focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `click`, you can use `focus`.

To make sure your elements are loaded, you also can add `window.onload` event.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].focus();
}
```

```html
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_ablz _aaoc" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px !important;"></textarea>
<button class="_acan _acao _acas" type="submit" disabled=""><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacw _adda _aad0 _aad6 _aade">Post</div></button>
```

If you want to enable that button, you can set `disabled` attribute true/false after textarea's value changed.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].focus();

  //enable/disable button when textarea value changes
  document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].onchange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("_acan _acao _acas")[0].disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("_acan _acao _acas")[0].disabled = true;
    }
  }

  //trigger onchange manually
  document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].value = "Testing"
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
  document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

```html
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_ablz _aaoc" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px !important;"></textarea>
<button class="_acan _acao _acas" type="submit" disabled=""><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacw _adda _aad0 _aad6 _aade">Post</div></button>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. For some reason, the ```.focus()``` doesn't seem to work on the website i'm working on.. But it worked in the examples I saw under this question. <br> I enabled the post button using the way you suggested, and I was able to click on it. But the comment wasn't actually posted. I refreshed my page, still can't see the comment.

Comment: I think your elements' classes have been changed after the page is refreshed, did you verify the elements' classes? @ichbinjay

Comment: I just added `window.onload` event to make sure your elements are loaded @ichbinjay

Comment: The class names remains the same after refreshing, but I noticed that when I manually click on text box, class name is changed to '_ablz _aaoc focus-visible', and ```data-focus-visible-added``` is added before the tag is closed. I can't copy is because it disappears on blur.

Comment: hmm the new class should not affect the element selector, I guess you should give more context for your question, we may try to find out what's your actual problem. @ichbinjay

Comment: well I'm trying to automate Instagram actions. I've already written the code for navigating through and liking posts, but I'm not able to automate comments @Nick Vu

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus on the textarea, symulate a keypress and only then click on the submit button

Comment: Hello, thank you for reaching out. Do you mean ```document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].focus();``` ? I tried that in chrome console, but it didn't work either..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to focus on the text area use `focus()` event instead of `click()` event

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].focus();
```

```html
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_ablz _aaoc" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px !important;"></textarea>
<button class="_acan _acao _acas" type="submit" disabled=""><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacw _adda _aad0 _aad6 _aade">Post</div></button>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. For some reason, the ```.focus()``` doesn't seem to work on the website I'm working on.. I mean, it worked in your example, and also in examples I saw on other websites. just not on my target website.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why in `document.getElementsByClassName("_ablz _aaoc")[0].click()` you are using two classes for selection as you can not do that with this method `getElementsByClassName` if you want to use multiple classes use `document.querySelectorAll('.class1,.class2')` and then you can use the click event on the element.
Hope it will help you in resolving the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for reaching out. As far as my understanding goes, ```.getElementsByClassName()``` is returning an array(or HTMLCollection), and I've used indexing(```[0]```) to access the particular element I want. I can't see where I'm performing click operation on 'two classes'...

Comment: `_ablz _aaoc` are these two classes or one single class? There is a space in between so I thought these are two classes.

Comment: that's just one single class